# Restrict write permission of sql table based on ip address

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

We need to restrict write permission of particular table in sql server.
But based on ip address of the particular server we need to enable write permission for particular table.
Is this possible in sql server permission scenario?

We have to prevent SQL injection in our application.
If the above restriction is not possible, can any one suggest us alternative way to prevent SQL injection on particular table?

Comment: Restricting a write permission does not prevent SQL injections. At all.

Comment: SQL Injection is prevented by using parameterized queries. Restricting users permissions will not prevent SQL Injections. Regardless, as a part of an overall secure environment it is a good thing to do.

Comment: This is like putting a piece of cheese with a note: "Not for mice!". This is not going to help against SQL injection. Use parameterization.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Already sql injection occurred in our application. so now the person who injected know our particular table details. parameterization will work and prevent from this scenario also? Can i get clear example or reference link regarding parameterization ?